# Is there a purpose to repeating identical media query expressions in CSS?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm looking at some legacy code and see the following media query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (min-width: 768px) and (min-width: 768px)
```

What is the purpose of the repeat identical `min-width` expressions, if any? I've never seen this before.

Comment: Just sloppy coding. No need to duplicate the first expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is either an authoring mistake, or the result of a misconfigured preprocessor or a preprocessor bug. If this was a deliberate workaround for some kind of browser bug or something (IE? Safari? Chrome?), it hasn't been documented anywhere on the web.

This statement is equivalent to

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
```

(but if you're familiar with the standard, you probably already guessed as much)